# How to work around Internet Explorer in Windows10 hiding svg:use element after moving it in DOM

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, svg

When I move a `svg:use` element from one `svg:g` to another `svg:g` then Internet Explorer on Windows10 *hides* it after the move.

**Example**:
Using jquery I move the `svg:g` with id "red_circle" from `svg:g` with id "source_group" to `svg:g` with id "target_group". In IE on Windows10 this hides the circle after the move.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<defs>
  <circle id="c1" cx="50" cy="50" r="40"/>
</defs>
<g id="source_group"> 
  <g id="red_circle" style="fill:red">
    <use xlink:href="#c1"></use>
  </g>
</g>
<g id="target_group">
</g>
```

```
$("#red_circle").click(function(e){
  $("#target_group").append(this);
});
```

Run this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HenningD/9pas6bay/7/) in Internet Explorer on Windows10 to see the issue: clicking the circle moves it to target_group and IE hides it. Other browsers like chrome or even IE on Windows8 or 7 don't.

**Here are my questions**:

1. Is this already addressed by Microsoft? If yes, is there a link to track the issue? If no, what is the best way to address this to Microsoft?
2. Do you know a workaround for this issue?

Comment: Internet Explorer 11 ?

Comment: For some reason, without the click event it works: https://jsfiddle.net/vLqb4Lz3/

Comment: I see this issue in IE11 (version 11.0.10240.16644) on Windows10 emulation with VMWare. When I emulate IE10 or IE9 within this IE11 browser I also see this issue.
Running "Edge" browser (version 20.10240.16384.0) in my Windows10 VMWare emulation I cannot reproduce this issue using the above linked fiddle.
And in IE11 (version 11.0.9600.18161) on my regular Windows8 machine I also cannot reproduce the issue with the fiddle.

Comment: Probably best to avoid jquery if you want things to work in IE. Chrome and Firefox magically fix up the namespaces, IE doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue recently with "query finding PREFIXES" I don't know why Edge didn't understand the namespace prefix, because I verified the xml document I had, had the node .

Case A) $(xml).find("a:\value")   -> works IE, Chrome & Sarafi, not in Edge

Case B) $(xml).find("value")   -> works in Edge

Solution)  $(xml).find("a:\value, value")   works everywhere